# Calling a method on Header view of UICollectionView some time after the creation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UIWebview in the header view of UICollectionView. I want to call the updateDataObject to pass the url to UIWebview after header view created, some time after

TestViewController (which has UICollectionView on)

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath


        ....
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = nil;

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
        AdViewHeaderView *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"AdViewHeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        reusableview = headerView;
        headerTmp = headerView;
        headerView.sectionMyLikeLabel.text = @"My Likes Here";
    }
    return reusableview;
}
...

NSURLConnection *httpCollection ... (this is to fetch the url link passed to the UIWebview);

   ....

   - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // here I get the link and want to call the header's updateDataObject
    }
```

Header View.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AdViewHeaderView : UICollectionReusableView

@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *sectionLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWebView *promotionView;

-(void)updateDataObject:(NSString *)link;

@end
```

In order to keep  headerview's memory from being reclaimed. I try creating a property called

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AdViewHeaderView *headerImp;
```

in TestViewController. Then later inside of connectionDidFinishLoading, I can call this method

```
[headerImp updateDataObject...]
```

However, 1 out of 10 times, headerImp has been reclaimed and becomes null. Any idea?

regards
Hammer

Answer (score 2):

Edit to reply after question edit :

As a collectionView can have one header view per section. Maybe scrolling makes multiples headerViews created instead of a single one (for indexPath.section == 0).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please refer to my updates on the question

Comment: This line is missing in your code : self.headerImp = headerView;

Comment: It is inside of if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
        AdViewHeaderView *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"AdViewHeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        reusableview = headerView;
        headerTmp = headerView;
        headerView.sectionMyLikeLabel.text = @"My Likes Here";
    }?

Comment: maybe there is a type headerTmp != self.headerImp

Comment: Changed, issue is still there.

Comment: Maybe you can track headerView object addresses by logging them using %p